# WaitForSingleObject is hanged in VC12 while it was working with VC9 compiler

Tags: c++, multithreading, pipeline

The below code was working with VC9 complier while the same code is not working in VC12. Do need to change any structure?

The problem is coming at `WaitForSingleObject ( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );` line.
after this line code is not executing.

```
bool MyClass::check()
{

    CSA_TRY
    {   
        HANDLE hPipeOutputRead      = NULL; 
        HANDLE hPipeOutputWrite = NULL; 
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi      = {0}; 
        STARTUPINFO si              = {0}; 
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa      = {0}; 

        // Create a pipe for the child's STDOUT. 
        sa.nLength = sizeof( SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES ); 
        sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 


        // Create pipe for standard output redirection. 
        CreatePipe( &hPipeOutputRead,           // read handle 
            &hPipeOutputWrite,          // write handle 
            &sa,                        // security attributes 
            0                           // number of bytes reserved for pipe - 0 default 
            );  // Create pipe for standard input redirection. 


        // Make child process use hPipeOutputWrite as standard out, 
        // and make sure it does not show on screen. 
        si.cb           = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
        //si.cb         = sizeof(si);
        si.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES; 
        si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; 
        si.hStdOutput  = hPipeOutputWrite; 
        si.hStdError   = hPipeOutputWrite; 


        TCHAR commandLine[ MAX_PATH ] = _T("cmd.exe ver"); 

        //spawn a new child process...
        CreateProcess(      NULL, 
            commandLine, 
            NULL, NULL, 
            TRUE, 0, 
            NULL, NULL, 
            &si, &pi
            ); 

        // Now that handles have been inherited, close it to be safe. 
        // You don't want to read or write to them accidentally. 
        CloseHandle( hPipeOutputWrite ); 

        // Now capture the application output by reading hPipeOutputRead.

        DWORD dwNumberOfBytesRead = 0; 
        CHAR szBuffer[ 65535 ]; 
        CString conOut; 
        BOOL bTest = TRUE; 

        bTest   =   ReadFile( hPipeOutputRead,              // handle of the read end of our pipe 
            &szBuffer,              // address of buffer that receives data 
            256,                    // number of bytes to read 
            &dwNumberOfBytesRead,   // address of number of bytes read 
            NULL                    // non-overlapped. 
            );

        szBuffer[dwNumberOfBytesRead] = 0;  // null terminate 
        conOut = szBuffer;

        WaitForSingleObject ( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

        // Close all remaining handles 
        CloseHandle ( pi.hProcess ); 
        CloseHandle ( hPipeOutputRead );

        return true;
    }
    CSA_CATCH_ANY
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: It waits for the process to close. Because you passed `INFINITE`, it will continue waiting until the process closes. This is the expected behavior. You aren't checking return values *anywhere* in this code, so you can't actually have any clue about where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Also note that `WaitForSingleObject` is an OS function; it doesn't even know which compiler you used. That suggests the problem is elsewhere, e.g. in the code that would trigger the event you're waiting on.

Comment: Please provide a compilable [mcve]. And please compare https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the process `cmd.exe ver`. If you run this manually in Explorer (<kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) you can see that `cmd.exe ver` prints out the Windows version and then stays open. Your program waits until `cmd.exe ver` exits.

So you need to either close the opened `cmd.exe ver` (for example typing `exit`) or you need to change the command line to `cmd.exe /c ver`.

Another problem in your code: you are not setting `si.hStdInput`.

You really should add error checking to see what exactly fails with which error code.

Comment: I have tried with cmd.exe /c ver and with formatted string also eg: swprintf_s( commandLine1, L"%s /c %s", cmd, input );
Still it is not working.
conOut = szBuffer; is not getting the value of version.